# what is angular UI components ? can any one please tell me

Tags: angularjs

Is there any difference between custom directives and Ui components. please anyone tell me the difference and usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Component-var.html) is a '*reusable UI building block for an application*' which creates it's own view (new hierarchy of DOM elements) with behaviour.

```
@Component({selector: 'greet', template: 'Hello {{name}}!', directives:  [CustomDirective]})
class Greet {
  name: string = 'World';
}
```

which could be used as html:

```
<greet></greet>
```

A [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) adds behaviour to an existing element (DOM) via event listeners.

```
angular.module('simpleDirective', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {  }])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      template: ''
    };
  });
```

which can be used as:

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
  <div my-directive></div>
</div>
```